# jQuery append with api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

New to javascript and jQuery and I have a question.

I'm trying to make a simple orderform with different categories and articles. The categories and articles are called from a RESTful webservice.

This is what I got so far. The first api call get's all the categories:

```
function createform() {
var dateval = '';
dateval += $("#dedate").val();

$.api.getArtCategories(dateval, getToken('user'), getToken('token'), function(response) {
    buildOrderform(response);
});

$('#orderform').show();
$("#ordersubmit").removeClass("disabled");
}
```

The buildOrderform function creates the html:

```
function buildOrderform(json) {
//create categories
var html = '';
json.forEach(function (entry) {
    var art_category = entry.art_category;
    html += '<div class="row form-group categorycontainer">';
    html += '<div class="col-md-8 categoryheader">';
    html += '<h3>' + art_category + '</h3>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
});

$("#orderlist").html(html);

//append articles to the categories
$(".categorycontainer").append("API-Call");
}
```

Here I'm stuck. The last statement loops through all the containers an appends new html. If I do this with `<p>test</p>` it works as expected.

But I want to get the HTML with another api call.

The second api call would be:

```
$.api.getArtItems(art_category, getToken('user'), getToken('token'), function(response) {
    builditemlist(response);
});
```

And the buildItemlist would be something like this:

```
function builditemlist(json) {
var item = '';
json.forEach(function (entry2) {
    var art_description = entry2.art_description;
    var art_id = entry2.art_id;
    var art_name = entry2.art_name;
    var art_price = entry2.art_price;
    item += '<div class="row form-group">';
    item += '<div class="col-md-8"><b>' + art_name + '</b><br>' + art_description + '</div>';
    item += '<div class="col-md-2">' + art_price + '</div>';
    item += '<div class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control article" id="' + art_id + '" type="text"/></div>';
    item += '</div>';

});
return item;
//$("#orderlist").html(item);
}
```

But how do I get the api call and the html creation into the append? And the actual `art_category` does have to get passed to the api call?

Comment: `$("#orderlist").html(builditemlist(response););`

Comment: API-call is asynchronous, so it won't be able to return to the append method. Better to put the append inside the `builditemlist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are asynchronous calls within an asynchronous call, so the creation loop is a little complicated. Below is an example how I would do it. I haven't tested it, so you might need to fix little mistakes, the general approach should work though.
I think I have names the functions so that it is easy to understand whats going on.

Two other tips:

- Make sure you catch errors and tell the user that something went    wrong. Example code is in comments.
- Its better to display the    categories only after they are created, so any display states related    to a successful request should be in the asynchronous callback.

Code:

```
function createform() {
    var dateval = '';
    dateval += $("#dedate").val();

    $.api.getArtCategories(dateval, getToken('user'), getToken('token'), function(re) {
        //should handle error
        // e.g. if(re.error){   }
        buildCategories(re,function(err,categories){ //will be called after all list items for each category are created
            if(err){
            //display error to user, see comment in build Categories
            }
            else{
                $("#orderlist").empty().append( categories );
                $('#orderform').show();
                $("#ordersubmit").removeClass("disabled");
             }
        });

    });

}

function buildCategories(categories,callback){

    var categoryItems = [];

    var requestNexCategoryContent = function(){
        if(categories.length ===0){
            callback(null,categoryItems)
        }
        else{
            var category = categories.shift()
                ,categoryItem = buildCategoryItem( category  )
                ;
            $.api.getArtItems(category.art_category, getToken('user'), getToken('token'), function(re) {
                //should catch errors her as well
                // e.g. if(re.error){ callback(err,null);return; }
                categoryItem.append( buildItemsForCategory( re ) );
                categoryItems.push( categoryItem )
                requestNextCategoryContent();
            });
        }

    }

    requestNextCategoryContent();

}

function buildCategoryItem(data){
    var item = '<div class="row form-group categorycontainer">';
        item += '<div class="col-md-8 categoryheader">';
        item += '<h3>' + data.art_category+ '</h3>';
        item += '</div>';
        item += '</div>';
     return $(item);
}

function buildItemsForCategory( list ){
    return list.map( function( i,data ){
        var item = '<div class="row form-group">';
            item += '<div class="col-md-8"><b>' + data.art_name + '</b><br>' + data.art_descriptionn + '</div>';
            item += '<div class="col-md-2">' + data.art_price + '</div>';
            item += '<div class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control article" id="' + data.art_id + '" type="text"/></div>';
            item += '</div>';
        return item;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thx. This async stuff gets mit puzzled ...
One problem I have is the `$.api.getArtItems`has as first parameter the category, which have to be passed.

Comment: Not a problem, I've edited my code in `requestNextCategory`.
Notice that I am now keeping the category data object and use the `art_category` property from it in `$.api.getArtItems`

Btw. Not sure if you have the hands on the development of the backend API as well. Ideally the API would return you the required data in on call, the successive calls from the browser are a little expensive, depending on how many categories you have.